# Does zero Fourier dimension imply there is no Rajchman measure?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $K\subset R^d$ be a compact set. It is well known that its Fourier dimension is defined by
$$\dim_F K=\sup\{s\ge 0: \exists \mu \in M_1(K) s.t. \hat{\mu}(x)=O(|x|^{-s/2})\}(|x|\to\infty),$$
where $M_1(K)$ denotes the set of probability measures with support in $K.$

My question is: Does the condition $\dim_FK=0$ imply that $K$ can not support a measure $\mu$ with decaying Fourier transformation?  In other word, there is no Rajchman measure spported on $K?$

Maybe there exists measure with decaying Fourier transformation according other ``speed" rather than polynomial speed. Can somebody give an example? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not follow. Since the Hausdorff dimension dominates the Fourier dimension, it suffices to establish the existence of a compact set $K$ of Hausdorff dimension zero that supports a Rajchman measure.

The last theorem of section 3 (attributed to Ivashev-Musatov 1962) of [Lyons's survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9640/509efbee86d4d80b9f9a40685ffda2484fa1.pdf) gives a considerably stronger version of this statement (note that $\mathcal U_0$ is defined in the introduction of the paper as the collection of sets that are annihilated by all Rajchman measures).